# Java: measure network bandwidth for a specific code segment

Tags: java, sockets

I want to add bandwidth measurements to my servers (written in pure java). I am thinking of an API that look like

```
MeasureBandwidthSignletone.getInstance().startMeasuring();
......
.....//here I may connect to a db or using http (HttpUrlConnection)...
.....
MeasureBandwidthSignletone.getInstance().endMeasuring();
```

Problem is that I have many different kinds of code that access the network (jdbc, HttpUrlConnection, FTP, etc...) I was wondering if I can somehow attach a threadlocal monitor to sockets, which will allow me to know how many bytes were uploaded or download.

I know one way would be using ASM / AspectJ to change the byte code - but is there any simpler way to plug in to the java socket API?

Thank you

Comment: The only way to monitor a Socket is through code injection. A simpler approach is to run this test on a machine by itself and monitor the network usage of the machine.

Comment: What about setting a custom made SocketFactoryImpl? Can that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What about setting a custom made SocketFactoryImpl? Can that work?

That could also work for a specific version of the JVM.  If you know which version you are targeting you could create a modified version of this class.

The reason this won't work for a generic JVM is this class uses internal APIs which can be different between versions which is why byte code injection is more likely to work for a broad range of JVMs.

Comment: Can it work for:: 
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)?

Comment: @user967710 if you have a copy of the source for this build, you can modify it and use your modified version if you don't consider this isn't allowed in the license.